# Adapting CoefficientList (and the related functions) to work with Laurent polynomials

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

Is there a slick way to make `CoefficientList` (and the other similar functions, `CoefficientRules` etc.) work for Laurent polynomials (i.e. where negative exponents can occur), if I don't know *a priori* what the largest negative exponents are? I can of course do some ugly *ad hoc* thing by hand, but I'm looking for a method that works generally.

Any tips?

Comment: Can't you just search for the largest negative power in your expression using Cases or so? Dividing your expression by this power should enable you to use CoefficientList, or not?

Comment: You can use the three argument form of `Exponent` to get at the smallest one: `In[73]:= Exponent[x^(-3) + x^2 - 4, x, Min]

Out[78]= -3`

Answer (score 5):

I propose a relatively compact method

```
coeffrul[pol_, x_Symbol] := {# -> Coefficient[pol, x, #]} & /@ Exponent[pol, x, List];
coeffrul[x^-1 + 2 x^1.5 + 3 x^3, x]
```

> ```
> {{-1 -> 1}, {1.5 -> 2}, {3 -> 3}}
> ```

It works not only with integer powers.

Comment: This certainly has limitations inherent to `Coefficient`. Try `Coefficient[a r^(2 e) + b r^(1 + 2 e) + r^(2 + 2 g) c, r, 2 e]`, for example. Would love to see a solution that can take out the coefficient of one exact power even for symbolic powers.

Answer (score 3):

As referred to in the comments:

For single variable polynomial:

```
coeffl[pol_, s_Symbol] := Module[{e, mod},
  e = Exponent[pol, s, Min];
  mod = s^(-e) pol;
  CoefficientList[mod, s]
  ]
```

will produce coefficient list.

To obtain cofficient of exponent:

```
coeff[pol_, s_Symbol, exp_] := Module[{e, mod, M, cl},
  e = Exponent[pol, s, Min];
  M = Exponent[pol, s, Max];
  mod = s^(-e) pol;
  cl = CoefficientList[mod, s];
  exp /. Thread[Range[e, M] -> cl]
  ]
```

Test example:

```
coeffl[1 - 2/z^3 - 1/z^2 + 2 z + 3 z^2 + 4 z^3 + 5 z^4 + 6 z^5,z]
```

yields:

```
{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

and

```
coeff[1 - 2/z^3 - 1/z^2 + 2 z + 3 z^2 + 4 z^3 + 5 z^4 + 6 z^5,z,-3]
```

yields -2

**EDIT**

Above not ideal (general):

```
coefflg[pol_, s_Symbol] := Module[{e, mod},
  e = Exponent[pol, s, Min];
  If[e < 0,
   mod = s^(-e) pol;
   CoefficientList[mod, s],
   CoefficientList[pol, s]
   ]
  ]


coeffg[pol_, s_Symbol, exp_] := Module[{e, mod, M, cl},
  e = Exponent[pol, s, Min];
  M = Exponent[pol, s, Max];
  If[e < 0,
   mod = s^(-e) pol;
   cl = CoefficientList[mod, s];
   exp /. Thread[Range[e, M] -> cl]
   , Coefficient[pol, s, exp]
   ]
  ]
```