# How can I quickly extract a specific coefficient in a Laurent polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have a Laurent polynomial for the following:

```
t[1]/(t[2] t[3]) + t[2]/(t[1] t[3]) + (t[1] t[3])/t[2] + (t[2] t[3])/t[1] + 1/(t[2] t[4]) + t[2]/t[4] + t[3]/(t[1] t[4]) + (t[1] t[3])/t[4] + t[4]/t[2] + t[2] t[4] + t[4]/(t[1] t[3]) + (t[1] t[4])/t[3]
```

Is there an efficient method to extract the constant multiplying the $n$-th power efficiently?  For high values of $n$ (e.g., extracting the $40$-th power) expanding the polynomial is not efficient!

Comment: Maybe this post can be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33302/8822

Comment: I don't understand what your terms mean.  A Laurent polynomial involves a sum of powers of $t$ but what are your $t[ ]$s?

Comment: It is a Laurent polynomials in four variables, t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4]